# Parsing a date in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, date-parsing

First of all thanks in advance for helping, the community is great.
I have a problem parsing my date and time. Here is my code:

```
var date = mail.bodyText.match(/\=\= date \=\=\s*(.*[^\s*])/);

if (date) {

        var string1 = date[1].match(/^\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2}/);
        var string2 = date[2].match(\s(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}));
        var string3 = date[3].match(\s(\+\d{4}));

        var parts1 = string1.split("-");
        var parts2 = string2.split(":");

        if (parts1 && parts2)
        {
                var dt = new Date(parseInt(parts1[0], 10), parseInt(parts1[1], 10) - 1, parseInt(parts1[2], 10), parseInt(parts2[3], 10), parseInt(parts2[4], 10), parseInt(parts2[5], 10));
        }

        date_final = dt;
}
```

`date_final` is defined elsewhere, and is in Date Time Picker format, and here is the input I am trying to parse:

```
blabla
== date == 
2016-02-13 16:22:10 +0200 
blabla
```

Every time I execute the code, I get a parsing problem. The variable `date_final` cannot handle the parsed date. What do you think is missing from this code?

Update:

Here is what I'v etried out. Impossible for me to locate what's wrong:

```
var date = mail.bodyText.match(/\=\= date \=\=\s*(.*[^\s*])/);

if (date) {
        var initial = date[1];
        var formated = initial.substring(0, 19);
        var final = formated.replace(/-/g, '/');
        var last = new Date(final);
        Field = last;

        logging += "{date=" + Field + "}";
}
```

The code is actually parsing an email and sending the result over SSL. What surprises me the most is that the logs keep posting the following output of the date i naddition to the "parsing issue": date=Sat Feb 27 2016 16:22:10 GMT+0200 (CEST).

Do you think the problem comes from the code or could be related to how the appliance this code implemented on can handle it?

Thanks

Jane

Comment: `parts2[3]` and `parts2[4]` and `parts2[5]`? should it be `parts2[0]` and `parts2[1]` and `parts2[2]`?

Comment: What are you trying to parse it to? Do you need to keep the timezone?

Comment: `new Date('2016-02-13 16:22:10 +0200'.substring(0, 19).replace(/-/g, '/'))` should work in most kinds of browser.

Comment: Hi Terry, true, I mistyped it:). Will try out your second proposition, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering in comment.

Here's one solution to your question:

```
var dateStr = '2016-02-13 16:22:10 +0200';

// get yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
var formatedStr = dateStr.substring(0, 19);

// get yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss in case of working on most of the browsers
var finalStr = formatedStr.replace(/-/g, '/');

// Date object can easily parse the datetime string we formated above    
var date = new Date(finalStr);
```

Answer (score -1):

[**`Date`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object can parse complex strings.

Mail providers usually follow an `RFC` on how timestamps should be written, thus allowing other programming languages to heavily support it.

Just pass your string into date object and it will convert it for you.

---

```js
let mailStr = `blabla
== date == 
2016-02-13 16:22:10 +0200 
blabla`;

let regex = mailStr.match(/\=\= date \=\=\s*(.*[^\s*])/);

let dt = new Date(regex[1]);

console.log(dt);
```

---

The output is described in [`ISO-8601`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: The problem with this is that [JavaScript supports RFC2822 and (simplified) ISO 8601](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) only. Everything else is browser-specific and your code fails in Firefox, for example.

Comment: Hi Alex, Will try out your proposition and get back to you. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @str I'll presume that the email that OP is trying to parse is browser-specific.

Comment: @Alex What do you mean by "the email [...] is browser-specific"? The format of an email is standardized, how can it be browser-specific?

Comment: @str Misread what you said. You mentioned that it will not work on Firefox, OP hasn't mentioned anything about compatibility.

Comment: @Alex Everyone expects websites to work in every browser so that is a very bad excuse. Your code fails in Firefox and Safari, but works in Chrome.